# Wi-Fi not working on an Intel NUC (NUC7i5BNK) running Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-driver, intel-nuc

I just got my hand on an old NUC (NUC7i5BNK) and I installed a fresh Windows 10 Pro on it and installed all the drivers from the [official page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/95061/intel-nuc-kit-nuc7i5bnk/downloads.html), but for some reason it can't detect any Wi-Fi network.

It says:

> “No Wi-Fi networks found.”

Not sure what I'm missing, and I'd like to add that Bluetooth works fine.

Comment: Look in Device Manager and see if the wired and wireless network cards are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the antennas are actually connected to the WiFi chip. They may have become dislodged during shipping and are necessary to get a WiFi signal.

[image]

You will have to remove the NVMe SSD (if fitted) to get to these connectors. The NVMe connects to the black connector to the  right of the wifi chip.

Comment: Yep it was the antennas, they were completely disconnected. I reconnected them and now everything works fine. Thanks.